# Setting default values with selectize api for listbox in selectize.js

Tags: selectize.js

I am trying to set default value upon page load in a dropdown listbox which loads value thru an ajax call. Not able to set values using setValue method as suggested in the docs. Please help. Following are code snippets from the project

HTML

```
<select name="country" placeholder="Please Select Country  ..."></select>
```

Data population JS code

```
  $('[name="country"]').selectize({
    valueField: 'name',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: 'name',
    preload: true,
    create: false,
    render: {
      option: function(item, escape) {
        return '<div>' + escape(item['name']) + '</div>';
      }
    },

    load: function(query, callback) {
          $.ajax({
            url: '/countrydata',
            type: 'GET',
            error: function() {
                callback();
            },
        success: function(res) {
            callback(res);
        }
      });
    },
  });
```

Default Value Setting Code

```
$('[name="country"]').selectize();
$('[name="country"]')[0].selectize.setValue("Japan");
```

Is there a hack where I can circumvent the problem ? I am been trying to get this work for couple of days now.

Thank you for reading. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but I believe your issue is that you're attempting to set the value to an option that doesn't exist in the list. You need to add the option first:

```
$('[name="country"]').selectize();
var item = {};
item.name = "Japan"; //Based on your render function, which uses item['name'] and labelField, searchField, etc.
$('[name="country"]')[0].selectize.addOption(item);
$('[name="country"]')[0].selectize.setValue(item.name);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. This is exactly what I was looking for. Have a great day.

Comment: Now I am suck with another related problem. When I get the country back from the database, I get country code .. 1, 41, 45 etc which I can set it to item.id. How do I get item name from the ajax call back based on the id ? I am just not able to figure how to set the name based on id.

Comment: To be shorter use `var item = {name:"Japan"}` instead of second and third lines.